# JWT Token generated from c# doesn't match with Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jwt

I'm using following java script code to generate jwt token:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.base64.js"></script>
    <script src="js/aes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/aes-json-format.js"></script>
    <script src="js/hmac.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sha256.js"></script>

    <title>Cryptography</title>
</head>

<body>
   <div>
     <div id="jwtToken" style="font:14px bold;  word-wrap: break-word;" />
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e){
      var data = {
        user_type: "tmr",
        user_id: "OFhMQVZaS1l0SVFQNGtyaUpoOWRodz09",
        accesstoken: "F4111553-802B-B45C-F8DB-627D5933691E"
      }
      var payload  = {
        "iat": 101,
        "nbf":101,
        "exp":161,
        "iss":"offers/index",
        "jti":'',
        "data": data
      };
      var secret_key = "pa@987";
      var n_header = {alg:"HS256",typ:"JWT"};

      var enc_header = $.base64.encode(JSON.stringify(n_header));
      var enc_payload =$.base64.encode(JSON.stringify(payload));

      console.log("---- encrypted header---")
      console.log(enc_header);
      console.log("---- encrypted payload---")
      console.log(payload);

      var token = enc_header + "." + enc_payload;

      var sh_h256 = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(token, secret_key);
      var jwt_enc_signature = $.base64.encode(sh_h256);

      token = token + "." + jwt_enc_signature;

      console.log("---- JWT  Signature ---");
      console.log(jwt_enc_signature);

      console.log("----- JWT Token ------");
      console.log(token);

      document.getElementById('jwtToken').innerHTML = token;
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Above code gets me following token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjEwMSwibmJmIjoxMDEsImV4cCI6MTYxLCJpc3MiOiJvZmZlcnMvaW5kZXgiLCJqdGkiOiIiLCJkYXRhIjp7InVzZXJfdHlwZSI6InRtciIsInVzZXJfaWQiOiJPRmhNUVZaYVMxbDBTVkZRTkd0eWFVcG9PV1JvZHowOSIsImFjY2Vzc3Rva2VuIjoiRjQxMTE1NTMtODAyQi1CNDVDLUY4REItNjI3RDU5MzM2OTFFIn19.YjdlNTcxMTliNGM0OTA2ZTVmYzY2NTlkZmQ1ZTk3YmQ0NDk4MGJmZGI3YzZlZjUzNGZmZTk3YmRmYjAwNmUyZA==
```

and I'm using following c# code to generate the same token:

```
static void test()
{
    dynamic data = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    data.user_type = "tmr";
    data.user_id = "OFhMQVZaS1l0SVFQNGtyaUpoOWRodz09";
    data.accesstoken = "F4111553-802B-B45C-F8DB-627D5933691E";

    Object payload = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "iat", 101 },
        { "nbf", 101 },
        { "exp", 161 },
        { "iss", "offers/index" },
        { "jti", "" },
        { "data", data }
    };

    var secret_key = "pa@987";

    dynamic n_header = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    n_header.alg = "HS256";
    n_header.typ = "JWT";

    byte[] headerBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(n_header));
    byte[] payloadBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload));

    var enc_header = Base64UrlEncode(headerBytes);
    var enc_payload = Base64UrlEncode(payloadBytes);

    var token = enc_header + "." + enc_payload;

    var sh_h256 = JsonWebTokenConvert.Converter.CreateToken(token, secret_key);
    var jwt_enc_signature = Base64UrlEncode(sh_h256);

    token = token + "." + jwt_enc_signature;

    Console.WriteLine(token);
}

private static string Base64UrlEncode(byte[] input)
{
    var output = Convert.ToBase64String(input);
    output = output.Split('=')[0]; // Remove any trailing '='s
    output = output.Replace('+', '-'); // 62nd char of encoding
    output = output.Replace('/', '_'); // 63rd char of encoding
    return output;
}

public static byte[] CreateToken(string message, string secret)
{
    secret = secret ?? "";
    var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(secret);
    byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
    string base64Message = Convert.ToBase64String(messageBytes);
    byte[] base64Bytes = encoding.GetBytes(base64Message);

    using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
    {
        byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(base64Bytes);
        return hashmessage;
    }
}
```

which is getting me following token which doesn't match with the one generated from java script code:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjEwMSwibmJmIjoxMDEsImV4cCI6MTYxLCJpc3MiOiJvZmZlcnMvaW5kZXgiLCJqdGkiOiIiLCJkYXRhIjp7InVzZXJfdHlwZSI6InRtciIsInVzZXJfaWQiOiJPRmhNUVZaYVMxbDBTVkZRTkd0eWFVcG9PV1JvZHowOSIsImFjY2Vzc3Rva2VuIjoiRjQxMTE1NTMtODAyQi1CNDVDLUY4REItNjI3RDU5MzM2OTFFIn19.EZtxFXJTwDExZFJuRcPppmY7d97MsUcfpxq1JI1VSBw
```

I'm bit clueless about the problem here. Can someone please help me to head in the right direction.

Comment: Will, those are dummy codes. Thanks

Comment: Try to **base64urlencoding** instead of base64 encoding here: `var jwt_enc_signature = $.base64.encode(sh_h256);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JavaScript version you do Base64 encoding of header and payload and put it together as a string:

```
var enc_header = $.base64.encode(JSON.stringify(n_header));
var enc_payload =$.base64.encode(JSON.stringify(payload));
var token = enc_header + "." + enc_payload;
```

then calculate the key and do base64 encoding on it:

```
var sh_h256 = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(token, secret_key);
var jwt_enc_signature = $.base64.encode(sh_h256);
```

In C# you do the same as in JS before you create the signature:

```
var enc_header = Base64UrlEncode(headerBytes);
var enc_payload = Base64UrlEncode(payloadBytes);
var token = enc_header + "." + enc_payload;
```

but instead of encrypting the token you call `CreateToken`

```
var sh_h256 = JsonWebTokenConvert.Converter.CreateToken(token, secret_key);
```

but unfortunately your `CreateToken` function does again a base64 encoding of the message before it calculates the signature:

```
public static byte[] CreateToken(string message, string secret)
{
    ...
    string base64Message = Convert.ToBase64String(messageBytes);
    ...
    using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
    {
        byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(base64Bytes);
        return hashmessage;
    }
}
```

which leads to a different signature in the two versions.

As descibed on https://jwt.io/introduction/

You have to create the signature as you do in your JS version and the do base64Url encoding of the signature, which is then concatenated to the token.

So your JS version looks correct, but I can't verify the token on https://jwt.io

Comment: Hi jps. Thanks a lot for your time and answer. It helped me to fix the c# code and now I can successfully verify the generated token on jwt.io. but it still does not match with java script code. Looks like some problem with js implementation. I will look into and update

Comment: You're welcome. Have you been able to fix the js problems?

Comment: Yes, I fixed the JS code too. Had to do some modifications in the core encryption library.

Comment: Not yet eligible to upvote. Shame on me. Marked your answer as accepted :)